# SQL Query - Are they the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two Queries here that will generate the same result.
Which do you think is better or maybe they are totally the same.

Query 1

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(col_1, col_2) AS col_1
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.col = ISNULL(col_1, col_2)
```

Or Query 2

```
WITH cte_table_1 AS
(
    SELECT
         ISNULL(col_1, col_2) AS col_1
    FROM table_1
)

SELECT
    cte_table_1.*
FROM cte_table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.col = col_1
```

Comment: Check the execution plan. I wouldn't be surprised if both statements result in exactly the same plan

Comment: You would be much better placed to learn about tools such as execution plans rather than asking multiple "how do these two queries compare" questions.

Comment: Exactly.. Looking forward on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to predict this.

In general: SQL-Server is **not a procedural engine** working down statements, one after the other, as you've set this in your code. You tell SQL-Server what you want, and **the engine will decide, what is the best way to achieve this**. And **this is done pretty well!** This may vary from one call to the next depending on statistics, parallel actions, usage of memory, CPU or HD.

Even if it looks like this, the **CTE is not handled like a table**. Queries with multiple CTEs look like *Oh, pick this result, than fetch these, now let's call these rows and now go into the main query!* But the **engine might decide for a completely different order of execution**.

In your simple case I'd assume, that the engine is smart enough to see, that your queries are the same structurally.

Check the execution plans to see further details.

### Update

You say: *if they have the same EP result then we can say that its up to the user which is better to them as what is preferable to them?*

Why should your users think about the **internal** structure of a query at all? It depends on so many factors you cannot control! You cannot even be sure, that the next call will be the same as the one before...

My strong advise is: **Do not even try to out-smart the engine!** Thousands of hours were spent into its algorithms... You should rather think about things like readability and maintenance...

Comment: Yep! Execution plans will tell further details. I assume that there's a simple explanation on this case rather that reading EP.

Comment: @AlvinSantos No, there is not... I'd assume, that the engine will be able to fully inline `WITH cte_table_1 AS
(
    SELECT
         ISNULL(col_1, col_2) AS col_1
    FROM table_1
)` into the rest. If you want to **generally understand** this  to predict the behaviour for similar but more complex queries, this will lead you into darkness... In *real-world* scenarios things won't be that easy...

Comment: For instance, if they have the same EP result then we can say that its up to the user which is better to them as what is preferable to them? Or maybe it depends to the complexity of the rest query.

Comment: Thank you much Shinogo. noted this (readability and maintenance)

Answer (score 1):

1. A CTE is essentially just a disposable view. It will pretty much never make a query any faster than just putting the CTE code into a FROM clause as a table expression.
2. You have to use `ISNULL(col_1, col_2)` instead of `ISNULL(col_1, col_2, col_1)`
3. The first query is a better choice because a simple query with one join has a better performance than using CTE
4. Read more on CTE [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table)

Comment: better to use coalesce

Comment: Remarks: for (1), the proper term is `derived table` ; for (2) on SQL Server, `ISNULL` is usually preferred. `COALESCE` has side-effects. Read about those [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull).

Comment: I used ISNULL(col_1, col_2) for basic example. What if I changed that to a complex one which is case to case situation, should I repeat it again to where clause or should I boxed them to WITH statement.

Comment: If getting complex. You have to check both estimated execution plan

Comment: yep.. EP will give the answer. But I'd like to know more details. Btw, thanks.

Comment: It is depending on created indexes, statistics, server memory, data size, query complexity ,.... i dont think you can get a specific answer without giving us the complete code

Comment: Actually my code was simple as that, if there will be more complex code which will take the same scenario then maybe I can figure it out what is better between them. We already know that SQL will optimize its own query when it is executed, but logically thinking it's better to know why.

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` requires 2 argumnets

`COALESCE` we can pass multiple arguments

First query is better comparing to performance  because it is simple inner join but second query is some what not considered

Comment: The operator `IS NULL` is something different then the function `isnull()`

Comment: "a CTE should never be used for performance.": - care to explain that statement?

Comment: sorry to post answer answer quickly i wrote like that i removed..@MitchWheat

Comment: The first two lines are irrelevant. The rest is wrong. It is exceedingly unlikely that there will be any difference in plan or performance. (and what does `second query is some what not considered` mean anyway?)

Comment: see at staring he passed three arguments inside isnull() so inplace of isnull please pass coalesce i posted ..@MartinSmith